# How to add @Delegate to a field in Groovy inside an AST Transformation

Tags: groovy, annotations, delegates, transformation, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm writing an AST Transformation and I need to create a field inside my AST which has the `@Delegate` annotation.

I have a class A which I apply the annotation to.

```
@MyAnnotation
class A{ }
```

MyAnnotation has MyAnnotationASTTransformation where I'm trying to create a field of type B and add it the class A. Desired result after compilation:

```
class A{
    @Delegate
     B object = new B()
 }
```

Inside my ASTTransformation I tried AstBuildet.buildFromString

```
List<ASTNode> astNodeList = new AstBuilder().buildFromString(
 CompilePhase.CONVERSION,
 String.format(
  "class A{\n" +
  "  @Delegate\n"+
  "  B b = new B()\n"+
  "}\n"
 )
)

List<FieldNode> fieldNodeList =((ClassNode)astNodeList.get(1)).getFields()
classNode.addField(fieldNodeList.get(0))
```

Adding this to my project gives the following error:

```
8: class Delegate is not an annotation in @Delegate
```

Without @Delegate it works just fine, can I add the @Delegate manually somehow inside my ASTTransformation?